Do we need to do the SELCAL check if given an HF frequency by datalink?
If the controller sent us a message through datalink to monitor HF frequency (P xxxx S xxxxx ) and continue CPDLC, do we need to do the SELCAL check?

Is the HF frequency your currently assigned frequency or is it a new one?

A NEW ONE. USE VHF CURRENTLY.

Then yes, you are required to either do a SELCAL check or continuously monitor the frequency. I didn't have time to write up a full answer with references though!

@Lnafziger pls write in detail, i need to check the references
